# Spring WebFlow + Spring Security: use expression instead of role

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflow

I created a CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler to check users on a db table by searching for a function id. I want to change my roles on every function with only some db update and a restart of the context, without recompile and editing a mountain of XML.

I want to use SpringSecurityExpression inside a webflow! Like I can do in any other parts of Spring...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <secured attributes="isFUUU('key')" />

    <view-state id="main" view="dashboard/main.html" >
    </view-state>

</flow>
```

How can I make isFUU("key") working? it's a custom CustomAccessDecisionManager needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround

I had to debug 20 classes of spring security and webflow  to discover that in SecurityFlowExecutionListener even if you set spring security to work with expression, the listener will be role-based only.
I found that for parsing expression a would need a specific type config attribute, WebExpressionConfigAttribute to be precise. 
But it's not a public class!!! https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-1727 . 
So as suggested in this OLD Jira, I needed to creat my CustomSecurityFlowExecutionListener in the same package (org.springframework.security.web.access.expression)

Here the example

CustomSecurityFlowExecutionListener:

```
package org.springframework.security.web.access.expression; //First part of the trick!

import foo.bar.example.services.security.CustomAccessDecisionManager; 

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDecisionManager;
import org.springframework.security.access.ConfigAttribute;
import org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig;
import org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityFlowExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.webflow.security.SecurityRule;

/**
 * Force Spring WebFlow Security listener to use expression!
 * 
 * @author roberto.gabrieli
 */
public class CustomSecurityFlowExecutionListener<T > extends SecurityFlowExecutionListener
{

    /**
     * Convert SecurityRule into a form understood by Spring Security Force the usage of WebExpressionConfigAttribute!
     * 
     * @param rule
     *            the rule to convert
     * @return list of ConfigAttributes for Spring Security
     */
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected Collection<ConfigAttribute> getConfigAttributes(SecurityRule rule)
    {
        // Get Access Decision Manager to find if has my expression handler
        AccessDecisionManager adm = getAccessDecisionManager();

        ExpressionParser ep = null;
        //  Check if is my CustomAccessDecisionManager so I can use my expressions
        if ( adm instanceof CustomAccessDecisionManager )
        {
            ep = ((CustomAccessDecisionManager) adm).getWebSecurityExpressionHandler().getExpressionParser();
        }

        List<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes = new ArrayList<ConfigAttribute>();
        for ( String attribute : rule.getAttributes() )
        {
            if ( ep != null )
                // this will end the trick with fireworks!
                configAttributes.add(new WebExpressionConfigAttribute(ep.parseExpression(attribute)));
            else
                configAttributes.add(new SecurityConfig(attribute));
        }
        return configAttributes;
    }
}
```

WebFlow-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.4.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">
... 

    <bean id="securityFlowExecutionListener"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.MamSecurityFlowExecutionListener">
        <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="customAccessDecisionManager"/>
    </bean>

...
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution how to use Spring Expression Language in WebFlows. It's from the book "Pro Spring Security". In short, they define a custom `AccessDecisionManger` with a custom `AccessDecisionVoter` (`implements AccessDesisionVoter<org.springframework.webflow.engine.State`) and a custom `SecurityExpressionRoot`. So no need for an own listener as in your solution. These custom classes support expressions at the flow state level. The full example you can find on github with this [**link**](https://github.com/Apress/pro-spring-security/tree/master/ch09/ch10/webflow-example).